# How do you represent different versions of the same entity type (class) in the same UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, conceptual-model

I’m trying to figure out how to model a situation with following properties:

- there is a set of entity types Ei...Ej and a set of relationship types between those entity types Ri...Rj in the domain;
- one can distinguish at least two different versions of those entity and relationship types that are significant to different parts of the system *at the same time.*

In the simplest case, those different versions might be “real time data” version and “last approved snapshot” version. In this case, being significant to different parts of the system might translate into following:

- there are less privileged actors and use cases, that can only work with “last approved snapshot” version;
- at the same time there are more privileged actors with the same or different set of use cases, that can work with “real time data ” version;
- there are entity types Ex...Ey that either form relationships with entities ei...ej from “last approved snapshot” version or whose constraints reference values of attributes of entities ei...ej from “last approved snapshot” version;
- at the same time there are different entity types Ea...Eb that either form relationships with entities ei...ej from “real time data” version or whose constraints reference values of attributes of entities ei...ej from “real time data” version.

If I want to show all entity types Ei...Ej,  Ex...Ey and Ea...Eb from aforementioned example along with their constraints and relationships between them on the same diagram, how would I do that?

I was thinking about using two different classes for the same entity type: one class would represent “last approved snapshot” version of that entity type and another class would represent “real time data ” version of that type.

But I don’t like this approach very much as

- it seems redundant;
- I’m not actually sure what kind of relationship there is between two classes representing two different versions of the same entity type a how to represent that relationship in diagrams (maybe «derive» stereotype from standard profile would be appropriate here, but I'm not sure).

---

EDIT

Unfortunately, I can’t use examples from my work, so I’ve come up with this completely fictional one, but one that is also partially modeled after the problem I was trying to solve recently. I’ll be using popular “WorksInUsing” association to pay proper respects. This will make the question more concrete.

Also, to be clear, I’m trying to create conceptual model and not so much OOP/relational design/implementation model.

Let’s assume an entity type Employee.

Let’s assume an actor called “SkillAdministrator” managing following entity and relationship types:

- entity type Skill
- entity type Department
- relationship type KnownSkill between entity types Employee and Skill
- relationship type WorkInDepatment between entity types Employee and Department

Let’s assume, that changes in all those aforementioned entity and relationship types happen rarely but when they do they happen in very large batches and our skill administrator needs quite a time to process each such change.

After he’s finished processing the change, he runs PublishChange use case which creates a snapshot of entity and relationship types Skill and KnownSkill and makes that snapshot available to other users of the system.

Let’s now assume an actor called Manager managing following entity and relationship types:

- entity type Project
- relationship type WorksInUsing between entity types Employee, Skill and Project.

Only those Skills that existed at the last run of PublishChange use case can play role in WorksInUsing association. Also the pairs KnownSkill are precondition to triplets WorksInUsing, but again only those KnownSkill pairs, that existed at the last run of PublishChange use case.

At the same time Manager is managing WorksInUsing associations, SkillAdministrator can start working on processing the next big change in entity and relationship types that he manages. Manager doesn't see those changes, not until PublishChange use case is run again.

(Depending on the domain, there are multitude of different ways to handle deletion of particular skill or knownskill association by system administrator and then applying those changes - in the simplest case, both types could be assumed as permament, so new instances can be added but existing instances cannot be deleted, for examples laws work this way)

Comment: You would have an attribute and a constraint describing your limitations?

Comment: I was thinking about using constraints to describe my limitations. For example, I could model Ei as a single class and draw an association from Ex to that class with a constraint attached to Ei end of association claiming that only instances that existed at the last run of “data approval” use case could take part in this relationship.

Or I could create two classes to represent one entity type as described in the OP, connect them with some kind dependency and again attach explanatory constraint to that dependency. But I was hoping, that there is a more elegant or solution or maybe a pattern

Comment: What's your issue with constraints? Looking for ways to fall on your face more elegantly ;-) ? I think that's the most straight forward way and would be understood by anyone. Anyhow, wait for answers to come...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking about using two different classes for the same entity type

that can mean classes appear and disappear following the entity approval history !

Supposing there is not yet an approved version, so just a real time version evolving over time, when that version is approved there still only one version being both the last approved and the real time version, may be you can use the same class being now approved. Then a very first change must be done, so the last approved version still exists and is cloned to create the class for the real time version. When that real time version become approved the already existing last approved class must be deleted. Etc

An actor (in the non UML use case sense) have to access the right class to try to interact with.

I am not you sure you want that working at the meta model level.

---

A second way is to have a class always managing the last approved version and an other class managing the real time version, at a given time there is zero or one instance of each class, but at least one of them when an entity exists.

Supposing there is not yet an approved version so no instance of the last approved version class, so just an instance of the real time version class evolving over time. When that version is approved an instance of the approved version class must be created from the real time class instance then that least must be deleted. Then a very first change must be done, so the instance of the last approved version still exists and is cloned to create an instance of the class for the real time version. When that real time version become approved the already existing instance of the last approved class must be updated or deleted and an other instance created, and the instance of the real time class deleted. Etc

An actor have to access the right instance of class to try to interact with.

---

A third way is not to use different classes but different *instances* of the same class. During entity approval history the instances are created/deleted in the same way classes was in the first way. But the level is not the meta model.

Like in the previous way an actor have to access the right instance of the class to try to interact with.

---

A fourth way is to use the same instance for all versions of an entity existing at a time, the instance being able to react in the right way depending the *view* of it is used by an actor, also checking the actor is authorized or not. Each instance is created one time for a given entity, whatever the version(s) and the approval history.

Because there is only one instance the actor does not have to choose between several instances/classes. If you have association between entities they are all the time the same and do not have to be created/deleted depending on the versions of the entities.

Comment: `that can mean classes appear and disappear following the entity approval history !` not necessarily, snapshot class can be model and implemented as a derived class: two separate tables at relational level, two corresponding separate classes at application level and some a method to sync them. At the conceptual level on UML class diagram this could be model as two classes connected with some kind of dependency, but since it is conceptually a single entity type, I don't like this solution that much.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Four alternatives only?  :-) +1

Comment: @Christophe yes only four, my imagination is too limited to have more :-)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's not too much choice. Either you have to distinguish between inheritance
[image]
or via a flag
[image]

There are pros and cons for both solutions depending on the domain/context. In this case I would just tend to use the flag variant. Simply because it represents sort of a state that can change (see also [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) as suggested by [@Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe)). Choosing inheritance would make it complicated to make a non-approved snapshot an approved one (you would need to create a new instance and copy the contents).

In any case you need some constraint that will describe how access is limited so that certain actors can deal with the one or other variant. Just apply Occam's razor and don't try to find overly complicated models where simple ones will do as well. For a hobby purpose or to puzzle/stun others that's nice. But in practice?

Comment: Re your edit: It will not change what I said. What an actor may or may not perform depends on the rules you laid out. These come from requirements (hopefully) and lead to different use case scenarios. The implementing classes need to respect these constraints in order to implement the rule set correctly. That's just it.

Comment: Indeed approved vs non-approved are different states, and not different types of snapshots. The first approach using inheritance seems therefore appropriate only in the context of some kind of [state pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: @Christophe Thanks. I took the freedom to use the link above.

Comment: I also like the flag variant better. That said one could argue and it has been argued that on the conceptual level state and class is the same thing and choosing one or the other is the prominence of design. See for example: https://wiki.c2.com/?DualityBetweenStateAndClass

Comment: Good design is difficult. Often I follow my stomach and seeing it turn out well. Then, when asked "why so?" I can only tell: "it was my stomach". Computer science (like math) is more of an art than engineering. The engineering gives the very basics, but doing the real stuff turns out to be an art.